# UEC Exam ratio problem

Tags: ratio

I am going to sit for UEC exam and I am 15 years old and I need helps.

The question is as follow:

```
If p:q:r=3:5:7 and p+q=56
Find the value of p+q+r
```

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried?  What do you know about the relation between $p$ and $q$?

Comment: This seems fairly straightforward with a cursory understanding of ratios and it might be helpful to better articulate where you are stuck. Not trying to patronize, but if you don't understand ratios it might be helpful to be explicit about that.

Comment: Hint: Let $p=3x,q=5x,r=7x$ , then $p+q\cdots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ratios, $\frac{3q}{5}=p$ so replace $p$ by its expression in terms of $q$:

$\frac{3q}{5}+q=56$ which gives $q=35$ and so $p=21$ and using the ratios given, $r=49$.

So $p+q+r=21+35+49=105$

Comment: Thanks, I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: From our starting equation we get
$$p:q=3:5$$ so $$p=\frac{3}{5}q$$ and $$q+\frac{3}{5}q=56$$
Can you finish?

Comment: So
$$ \frac{8}{5}q=56$$ then $$q=35$$ From equation we know 
$$ \frac{q}{r}= \frac{5}{7}$$ then get $$r=49$$ At the end
$$p+q+r=56+49=105$$ 
Is it do like that?

Comment: Yes, this is the right result

Comment: Thanks a lot XD